# Engine in the .to_excel method in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The problem I'm having is that I make a pivot table and try to use the '.to_excel' method to write an xlsx formatted excel document for the pivot table, so for the engine parameter I used openpyxl.

```
import pandas as pd

def process_sales(file_name):
xl_file = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1')
report_table = xl_file.pivot_table(index='Gender',
                                   columns='Product line',
                                   values='Total',
                                   aggfunc='sum').round(0)
report_table.to_excel(f'Report',
                      sheet_name='ReportTable',
                      startrow=4,
                      engine='openpyxl')
return

process_sales('sales.xlsx')
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid extension for engine 'openpyxl': 'xlsx']'
```

And when I don't give a value for the engine, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'xlsx']'
```

Please let me know what I can do, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the first argument of .to_excel, you need to include the file extension (so update f'Report' to "Report.xlsx"). This should fix the issue without including an engine argument in .to_excel